# How can we alias the name of a child table column without using select in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Category Table Field:**`'id', 'title', 'slug'`
**Blog Table Field:**`'id','title', 'slug', 'short_desc', 'detail_desc', 'publish_date', 'seo_title', 'seo_keywords', 'seo_description', 'image', 'view_count', 'status'`

My query is fine with this syntax :

```
$data['rows'] = Blog::select('blogs.id','blogs.title', 'blogs.slug', 'blogs.short_desc', 'blogs.detail_desc', 'blogs.publish_date','blogs.seo_title', 'blogs.seo_keywords', 'blogs.seo_description', 'blogs.image', 'blogs.view_count', 'blogs.status', 'cat.id as cat_id')
                            ->join('categories as cat', 'blogs.category_id', '=', 'cat.id')
                            ->paginate($this->pagination_limit);
```

i want to create this type of syntax with alise category id:

```
$data['rows'] = Blog::join('categories', 'blogs.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                            ->paginate($this->pagination_limit);
```

So, how can i change categories table `id` as `cat_id` without using select. Because when i use without select and use blog id, it relapsed with category id.

Comment: Do you not want to use relationships for this?

Comment: yes, with relationship and without using select(field***)

Comment: Please can you add the code for you `Blog` model.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addSelect` like this:

```php
$data['rows'] = Blog::join('categories', 'blogs.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                     ->select('*')
                     ->addSelect('categories.id AS cat_id', 'blogs.id AS id') // alias categories id and rewrite the id for blogs
                     ->paginate($this->pagination_limit);
```